# Detect browser closing for angular 9 application

Tags: angular, onbeforeunload

I have got multiple answers for this, but the event like `window:unload` or `window:beforeunload` is getting triggered also when I login to application. My intention is when user closes browser or tab, he should be logged out.

But when I use these event listeners, they get called also when logging to application , I want them to trigger exclusively for window or tab close. I have used below code on my `app.component.ts` file. Can anyone help me on this?

```
@HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
unloadHandler(event) {
// ...
}
```

Comment: when logging? are you using some third party identity provider with OAuth,OpenID Connect or SAML?

Comment: Actually, If I am not wrong, event triggers when page is refreshed. I have one functionality where i need to reload the page.